# Post/Redirect/Get pattern for HTTP Responses with application/excel MIME Type

Tags: redirect, refresh, http-post, httpresponse

I want to post some data to the server, and in response, I want to create a CSV file, with `application/excel` as the MIME Type (recently recognized as Internet Media Type), to force the browser to open the generated CSV file in Microsoft Excel. However, I also want to prevent user from re-submitting the same info (re-posting the form) by any accident as the result of refreshing the page.

With simple CRUD operations, I use [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern, so that any further refreshing will only send HTTP Get Request to the server, without any parameter, thus not changing server's state ([Idempotence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence)).

What is the recognized pattern for stopping user from re-submitting (re-posting) the same info to the server, when the response is not a page, but a file?

Any idea?

Comment: Note that Firefox (and I think IE and Safari) warn if you try and re-POST data by refreshing the browser. The most common (client) approach I've noticed is using Javascript to disable the submit button. If you rely on some browser co-operation, you could also try setting and checking a cookie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Post/Redirect/Get pattern is an answer to a browsing event.
Here, there is no browsing action (the form submission only open a 3rd party app, i.e excel), and so any kind of browsing related pattern will be useless.

I suggest you use both a server side trace of the initial submission (with a unique token maybe), so you can prevent the file generation, and an easy to write client side script like `<form onsubmit="this.onsubmit = function(){ return false ; }">`

Answer (score 1):

I can offer you one other solution.

- Take hash (MD5/SHA256 ..) of your submitted data. The [hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) will be [fairly] unique.
- Put it in list in a session with a time limit, say 5 minutes.
- Even your user submit same data. Hash will be same and you can give error message to your user.

If different users can post same data, you can also hold user information in the list. And give error message according to user.